# Why is my code returning a list of the same object 4 times?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, list

**Issue:**
I need a `List` with type `resultAll` that should have one item in it per a row in the response table.  What I am getting is a list of these objects but each one is the object for the last row in my Response table.  I have even changed my data and it is always the last row. (ordered by ID)

Here is the `resultAll` class:

```
public class resultAll
{
public Response response = new Response();
public List<ResponseDetails> listofresponses = new List<ResponseDetails>();
public Question question = new Question();
public List<QuestionChoices> listofchoices = new List<QuestionChoices>();
}
```

This is my trouble code:

```
List<Response> query1 = (from r in db.Responses
                                 select r).ToList();
        List<Question> query2 = (from r in db.Questions
                                 select r).ToList();
        List<ResponseDetails> subquery1 = (from r in db.Responses
                                           join w in db.ResponseDetails on r.ResponseId equals w.ResponseId
                                           select w).ToList();
        List<QuestionChoices> subquery2 = (from r in db.Questions
                                           join w in db.QuestionChoices on r.QuestionId equals w.QuestionId
                                           select w).ToList();

        List<resultAll> testlist = new List<resultAll>();
        resultAll temp = new resultAll();
        foreach (var r in query1)
        {
            temp.response = r;
            var subquery3 = (from d in query1
                            join f in query2 on d.QuestionId equals f.QuestionId
                            where d.ResponseId == r.ResponseId
                            select f).First();
            temp.question = subquery3;
            temp.listofresponses = (from d in subquery1
                                    where d.ResponseId == r.ResponseId
                                    select d).ToList();
            temp.listofchoices = (from d in subquery2
                                  where d.QuestionId == r.QuestionId
                                  select d).ToList();

            testlist.Add(temp);
        }
```

Result:
 I'm returning `Json(testlist.Select(x=> new {id=x.response.ResponseId, brierscore=x.response.brierScore}), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`.

And these are the results: `[{"id":7,"brierscore":0.6498},{"id":7,"brierscore":0.6498},{"id":7,"brierscore":0.6498},{"id":7,"brierscore":0.6498}]`

DataBase Info:
I have a database that has 4 entities. Question, QuestionChoices, Response, ResponseDetails.  A question can have multiple responses. A question can have multiple choices.  A response can have multiple ResponseDetails.  And every responseDtail is linked to one Question choice.

Comment: What is the fascination with List and ToList? I inherited a code base that called ToList on anything that looked remotely like an IEnumerable and the result was three in-memory copies of everything, all the time. "Oh that's a nice looking IList<T> ... better call ToList!"

Comment: @Jon  It doesn't fix the issue. Any other ideas?  Is there any other information I could include?

Comment: @ta.speot.is  How else would you do this? I know that the code is not efficient, but I would like to see it running first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change :

```
    resultAll temp = new resultAll();
    foreach (var r in query1)
    {
```

into :

```
    foreach (var r in query1)
    {
      resultAll temp = new resultAll();
```

Otherwise you're always assigning values to the same `resultAll` instance inside your loop and adding the same instance into your list.

A new loop iteration erases values assigned in the previous one again and again until the end of the loop. That's why you get the last row 4 times.

Comment: Wow..... Fatal flaw in my understanding of .Add(). Thanks for helping me with this.